# Delete existing Validation Rule from Managed Org while new deployment

Tags: managed-package, validation, delete

While creating a managed package we created 2 validation rules on a object. Now while we are releasing a new managed package we need to remove one of the validation rule. Is their any way to remove it from the customers org while deploying the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, to delete validation rules from released managed packages. You can

1. Deactivate the rule in question **OR**
2. Change the body of the rule to *false*

After that you need to upload the package as managed released and upgrade it at the Org, where the old release has been installed.